# Show QDialog create in QtDesigner

Tags: c++, json, qt

I created next to my `MainWindow` a second form as `QDialog` with the Qt Designer.
My problem is how to show this Dialog by click a Button in the `MainWindow`.
If I use following code it creates a `newDialog` but I want to use the form I created in Qt Designer. How I can embed it?

```
QDialog *myDialog = new QDialog;
myDialog->show();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to create in QtDesigner a new dialog. In that dialog add all the stuff that you need and then save all the changes. The file that you will create will be a .ui. Add this file to your project.

After this create a header file and cpp file with the name that you want( it would be better if you use the same name as de ui file ). Then in the .h:

```
namespace Ui {
class QDialogExample;
}

class QDialogExample : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit QDialogExample(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~QDialogExample();

private:
    Ui::QDialogExample *ui; // This will be the acces to the widgets defined in .ui
};
```

And then in the .cpp file:

```
QDialogExample::QDialogExample(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::QDialogExample)
{
    ui->setupUi(this); // This will init all the widgets
}
```

Then in the slot of the QAction or your custom button add the call to

```
QDialogExample pDialogExample = new pDialogExample( this );
pDialogExample->show();
```

Anyway, to learn how it works, an all the process it would be advisable to use [QtCreator](http://qt-project.org/downloads), this is very helpfull in the creation of the dialogs and all the widgets that you need.